# Laravel 5.1 Where Condition In Many To Many relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello I'm very new in Laravel and, I'm having the following models :

```
organizations
-----------------
id
name

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\User' );
}

users
-----------------
id
name

organization_user
------------------
user_id
organization_id
```

The there is a many to many relationship between organization and user. Now I want to find the organization where the user belongs to. How can I add a where condition for the user in the relationship.

For example I want to find all the organization of the logged in user. I'm trying the following  :

```
$organisations       = Organisation::where('user_id' , '=' , $user->id)->paginate(10);
```

But its not working because user_id is in my Pivot Table. Please help and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to add reverse relation in user model than `$user->organization()`, i think that would easiest way to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use wherePivot() function in your code like

```
$organisations       = Organisation::with(array('user'=> function($query) use ($user){ 
                                $query->wherePivot('user_id' , '=' , $user->id);     
                            }) )->paginate(10);
```

May be this can help

Comment: Hello @Jitendra thank you for your quick reply. I tried your solution but I get this error  :

 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `organisations` where `pivot` = user_id)

Answer (score 0):

I think below code may help you

```
$organisations = Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('organizations')
    ->join('organization_user', 'organizations.id', '=', 'organization_user.organization_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'organization_user.user_id')
    ->where('users.id', '=', $user->id)
    ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this to your `User Model`

```
public function organizations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Organization');
}
```

and then will be something simple like this

```
$organizations = Auth()->user()->organizations;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all add your relations in your models:

User.php

```php
public function organizations()
{
return $this->hasMany(organization_user::class);
}
```

Or

```php
public function organizations()
{
return $this->hasManyThrough(organizations::class,organization_user::class);
}
```

I recommend the second one. For more information follow this:

[Laravel hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Please note that use same idea for organization model to create the relation